# How do I find the linear span of system?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the linear span of this system of polynomials $\{ 1+t^2 , t+t^2, 1+t+t^2 \}$?

Comment: Did you already work with linear spans of polynomials? What's the detail you have problems with?

Comment: I'm given a task to find the linear span, and i don't know how to do it

Comment: Do you have a definition of "the linear span" to work with?

Comment: @hasi, welcome to MSE! it is highly recommended to show some effort. Don't be discouraged because of the downvotes. Next time please add some thoughts about the question.

Answer (score 2):

Write down one such combination and check:

$$a(1+t^2)+b(t+t^2)+c(1+t+t^2)=(a+b+c)t^2 +(b+c)t+a+c$$

Suppose the above polynomial is the zero one, then

$$a+c=0\implies c=-a\;,\;\;b=-c=a\;,\;\;0=a+b+c=a\implies a=b=0$$

so the given polynomials are linearly independent and thus they span the space of all polynomials of degree up to $\;2\;$ (over the reals, I suppose, or over some other field), as they are three and that's the dimension of that space.